# Finally solved: The field must be a date

Tags: c#, jquery, date, validation, datepicker

**PROBLEM:**

I need to capture Date and Time data and I wrote this on my model class:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date of Birth cannot be empty")]
[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]

public DateTime DateofBirth{ get; set; }
```

And I have this datepicker setting:

```
$('#DateofBirth').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd MM yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                autoclose: true,
            });
```

When I pick a date, the textbox validation always says: "**The field Date of Birth must be a date**".
Even when I do not use datepicker (I write the date manually), it keeps saying like that.

I thought it has something to do with javascript or jquery as I read from many solutions offered. But, the validation keeps saying "The field Date of Birth must be a date".

After searching with no good results, I finally realized that date time format used by ASP.NET is **DIFFERENT** with the date time format used by jQuery.
As [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring?view=netframework-4.8) says, the general DataFormatString for Date and Time is 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM, so if I do not write exactly like that format, the validation error pops out. Even, when I use datepicker to fill the textbox.

Comment: If you want to post a solution then put it in an answer and not in your question

Comment: Ok, thanx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

Based on [this link](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-parseDate) and [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) I have to match the Date Time for for both ASP.NET model and jQuery datepicker.

So, I write custom Date Time format as **dd MMMM yyyy** in my model class:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date of Birth cannot be empty")]
[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString ="{0:dd MMMM yyyy}")]

public DateTime DateofBirth{ get; set; }
```

And the Date Time format as **dd MM yy** in jQuery datepicker properties, like this

```
$('#DateofBirth').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd MM yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                autoclose: true,
            });
```

I hope it helps.